# zsh is not finding my php executable

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using zsh on my Ubuntu VPS.

When I try to find version

`php -v
zsh: command not found: php`

and my php executable somehow got into

`whereis php
php: /usr/share/php`

How can I point it to right path?

Answer (score 3):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/php/bin
```

Add this to your .zshrc (assuming /usr/share/php/bin is the directory in which the php binary lives).

Comment: but my /usr/share/php is completely empty except `.registry`. weird

Comment: ahhh. stupid off me, I forgot to install php5-cli, in the process, and was confused little bit

Answer (score 0):

Ho you have to over write all commands to zsh

try this

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall PHP and overwrite any previous installation with this:

```
brew link --overwrite php
```